# How to Check $_POST Variables for NULL dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to loop through `$_POST` variables sent by a form to make sure none of them are empty or NULL. For example, if a form has 15 fields and is submitted. How to check that each of those 15 fields actually contained something other than NULL. I have multiple Forms but one validator class so I cannot specify the variable in the post array that need to be checked for each form.

I tried using foreach but that seemed to clear the `$_POST` array or corrupt it for some reason? The not working code is given below. If I `var_dump($_POST)` before I use the foreach and after the foreach I get an empty array after, but the correct values before. So I thing foreach is out of the question. Any Ideas?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
if ($value==NULL)
header ("Location: index.php")
}
```

Comment: please use `is_null($value)` to check in value is null or not

Comment: You should not check for `NULL`, they are either set or not and to check if it is empty, you should check for an empty string.

Comment: when i use foreach with $_POST even without a condition to execute it empties my post.

Comment: Did you put the var_dump before and after the loop at the same time?

Comment: No it doesn't. You should move the `header` redirect to see what is really happening. Although that shouldn't even work if you do a `var_dump()´ before it. Is this your actual code?

Comment: I did not have the header redirect in my code no. Therefore, all displayed on the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get any NULL values in $_POST array. If the form is submitted successfully and if the HTML form was not tampered with then all the fields will at least have some value or they will be empty ''. Do not use empty() function of PHP because it even considers 0 and a few other values as empty which might actually be the value. I believe this would be the correct way to write your code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === '')
        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    if (empty($value))
    header ("Location: index.php")
    }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   $valid = 15;
   if(empty($value))
     $valid --;

   if($valid == 15)
    {
     //validation ok
    }

   else  //This means at least one of the 15 fields is empty
     header ("Location: index.php")
}
```

Second solution: It's better to use `array` in your view, for example

```
<input type="text" name="Form[name]" />
<input type="text" name="Form[family]" />
... 
<input type="text" name="Form[address]" />
```

In this case, `$_POST['Form']` is an array and you can access it's elements. For example `$_POST['Form']['name']` equal to value of first textbox.
So your `foreach` should be like this:

```
foreach($_POST['Form'] as $key => $value)
...
```

Comment: whenever I use foreach even without a condition in it, it empties my $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

The code given by littlibex worked Thank

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
if ($value === '')
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

I only used two equal signs though.